# How to fix this issue "Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1"

Tags: java, spring-boot, jakarta-mail

I got a problem when trying to send an email with spring boot, the following error message:

Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: smtp.gmail.com, 587; timeout -1;

```
private void sendmail(EmailMessage emailmessage) throws AddressException, MessagingException, IOException {

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");

    Session session = Session.getInstance(props,
              new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                    return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                }
              });
```

Comment: Can you reach that host and port via other clients, like telnet or an email client?  The fact that it is a "couldn't connect" thing suggests that it isn't getting as far as the authentication being the issue.

Comment: The JavaMail FAQ has [tips for debugging connection problems](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#condebug).

Comment: Thanks for helping, I seem to have found a solution